# Codeigniter - URI Routes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

What my current URI looks like: `localhost/home/saved`, `localhost/home/view`

What I want it to look like: `localhost/saved`, `localhost/view`.

What my `home` controller looks like:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index() {
        //stuff
    }
    public function saved() {
        //stuff
    } 
    public function view() {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the `home` from the URL so the user can just visit `localhost/saved`, and other functions in my home without typing the `home` in the URL.

I tried putting these in the `routes.php` file but no luck.

```
$route['home/(:any)'] = "$1";
//that didn't work so I tried putting this:

$route['home/(:any)'] = "/$1";
//that didn't work either.
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$route['saved'] = 'home/saved';
$route['view'] = 'home/view';
```

> **Output** - `www.example.com/saved` and `www.example.com/view`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Comment: @TaylorSwift enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Group rule would be:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

Set this rule at the end of the routes because `(:any)` placeholder is greedy and would accept anything from URL if not speciffically pointed. Meaning: if you have controller `Product.php` with method `public function show($id){/*some code*/}` and want to approach to, route should be pointed before rule above.

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards).